# Is it more secure to set up a network so that there are no unused IP addresses?

Tags: ip

Is it more secure to set up a network so that there are no unused IP addresses?

Comment: Is the question here, "Is it more secure to set up a network so that there are no unused IP addresses?" I suppose it could make it more difficult for a rogue device to join the network, but not impossible. Meanwhile, it would make long term management of the network much more time-consuming.

Comment: @amincastellan so, how does this work in your estimation? If I want to add a new device, I need to re-subnet and reassign IPs for everything in the network so that there is no room in any subnet? That's not sustainable. And there are ways around not having an available IP, so it won't even be effective.

Comment: @FireQuacker Yeah that's the case. The network I'm speaking of is fixed and there will be no additional devices. Tanks.

Comment: I think it would be a nightmare for a little increase. There are easier things for the same task, too. Far, far ago I've seen a solution where some ppp-like protocol was used *on an ordinary, cable-based ethernet network*, and you needed to authenticate it, to be able to access it. Like on a wifi. They called it "microsoft proxy server" or what, although probably they misnamed it (ms proxy is some different thingy).

Answer (score 2):

No.

It only means that a rogue device can't use an unassigned IP. But it can get an IP by other means. And a device doesn't always need an IP.

It will only make things a little more difficult for an attacker, but it won't make *you* more secure.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't making it more difficult for an attacker mean better security? even if a little?